# How to aggregate all numbers of a column in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, aggregate

I'm trying to find some of all rows, with the same city name in an specific time. My table is :

```
CREATE TABLE fp_stores_data_test (
    time INTEGER,
    city VARCHAR(20),
    market_id INTEGER,
    product_id INTEGER,
    price INTEGER, 
    has_sold INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY (time, city, province, market_id ,product_id)
);
```

I want to create another table which is have `time`,`city` and `has_sold` columns. This one will show how much is sold in this city on that specific time. I don't know how to create this table using my first table. some sample input:

```
1594809782,city1,0,3588,54000,36
1594809782,city1,0,4813,59000,16
1594809782,city2,0,879,35000,33
1594809782,city2,0,2902,57000,13
1594809786,city1,0,3199,52000,5
1594809786,city1,1,864,35000,32
1594809786,city2,1,5297,37000,14
1594809786,city2,1,5339,40000,19
```

here, for `city1` in time `1594809782` we have two rows. These two row will be one row in the next table. with the same time and city but `has_sold` values will sum up in.

```
1594809782,city1,52
1594809782,city2,46
1594809786,city1,37
1594809786,city2,33
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I added some examples, I hope this help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this will do exactly what you need:

```
select time, city, sum(has_sold) has_sold 
from fp_stores_data_test 
group by time, city
order by time, city;
```

And you can store the query results in a table like this

```
select time, city, sum(has_sold) has_sold 
into [temporary table] fp_stores_data_agg
from fp_stores_data_test 
group by time, city;
```

[temporary table] is of course optional if you only need the aggregated table during the session and remove it afterwards.

Comment: thanks! 
can I use `sum(price*has_sold)` instead of `sum(has_sold)`?

Comment: Yes you can do that. BTW, do you really need so many fields in the primary key expression?

Comment: how can I add these rows instantly to another existing table? not a temporary table, or there is no difference?

Comment: `insert into existing_table(time, city, has_sold) select ... (the first query)`. Be careful however to not duplicate rows.